# Why fill() property overwittern in canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am learner html5 canvas
When I try to draw 2 circle (a circle within a circle).
When I draw a circle and fill it, it works.
when I draw second circle and fill it. it turns into first circle with second fill style.

What I try to create is a orange circle in a grey circle.
I tries many time to solve this but by each way it get problem..

Please check my code and let me know if i am wrong or what to do to fix this problem.

I have following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <style>
body{
}
#mycanvas{
    border:1px solid #000;  
    margin:0px auto;
    display:block;
}
#mycanvas1{
    border:1px solid #000;  
    margin:0px auto;
    display:block;
}
</style>
```

```
<body>

<canvas id="mycanvas" width="200" height="200">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<canvas id="mycanvas1" width="200" height="200">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var c = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    var b = document.getElementById("mycanvas1");
    var d = document.getElementById("mycanvas1");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var ctx1 = b.getContext("2d");
    var ctx2 = d.getContext("2d");
    ctx.fillStyle = "#bddfb3";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,200,200);
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.lineTo(200,200);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx1.fillStyle = "#f1b147";
    ctx1.arc(100,100,80,0,360);
    ctx1.fill();

    ctx2.fillStyle = "#222";
    ctx2.arc(100,100,50,45,180);
    ctx2.fill();
    ctx1.fillStyle="#fff";
    ctx1.font="72px Arial";
    ctx1.fillText("i",90,125);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello aditi. Please check this link - http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-shape-fill/

Answer (score 1):

This is a easy way to draw a orange circle inside a grey circle on canvas.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// orange circle
ctx.beginPath();
// centerX, centerY, radius, start angle, end angle, counterclockwise
ctx.arc(100, 100, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
ctx.fillStyle = 'orange';
ctx.fill();

// grey circle
ctx.lineWidth = 25;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'grey';
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
```